# How do I stop aggregate functions from adding unwanted rows to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wrote a line of code that groups the dataframe by column

`df = df.groupby(['where','when']).agg({'col1': ['max'], 'col2': ['sum']})`

After using the above code, the aggregated columns in the output has two extra rows, with 'max' and 'sum' taking up a column below the 'col1' and 'col2' index. It looks like this:

|  |  | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | max | sum |
| where | when |  |  |
| home | 1 | a | a |
| work | 2 | b | b |

This is my expected outcome:

| where | when | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| home | 1 | a | a |
| work | 2 | b | b |

I want to bring down both col1 and col2 down to the same row as location and month, and at the same time remove 'max' and 'sum' from showing. I couldn't really think of a way to make this work so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your expected output as well.

Comment: @MayankPorwal editted it.

Comment: If you remove the square brackets in your aggregation, pandas won't add "max" and "sum" column labels: `.agg({'col1': 'max', 'col2': 'sum'})` (then you can `reset_index()` to flatten the column index as Amit mentioned)

Comment: @tdy That's neat. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and pass column name to aggregate function in advance.

Use followoing:

```
df = df.groupby(['where','when']).agg(col1 = ('col1', 'max'), col2 = ('col2', 'sum')).reset_index()
```

Dataframe:

```
   where  when  col1  col2
0  home     1     1     1
1  work     2     2     2
2  home     1     3     3
```

Output:

```
   where  when  col1  col2
0  home     1     3     3
1  work     2     2     2
```

**Update:**

We can pass `as_index = False` to groupby which will stop pandas to put keys as the index and hence we don't need to reset the index afterwards.

```
df = df.groupby(['where','when'], as_index = False).agg(col1 = ('col1', 'max'), col2 = ('col2', 'sum'))
```

Comment: You could also add `as_index=False` to groupby.

Comment: Note that the other difference is how you aggregated. OP used `agg({'col1': ['max'], 'col2': ['sum']})` which actually adds `max` and `min` labels (even though OP doesn't want those labels).

Comment: @tdy Updated the explanation.

Comment: You don't need to reset index if you use `as_index=False` in groupby like `df.groupby(['where','when'], as_index=False).agg(col1 = ('col1', 'max'), col2 = ('col2', 'sum'))`

Comment: @Vishnudev I have added it as an update. Thanks.